# How downloads of NPM package increase?

Tags: npm-install, npm-publish

I have posted a package on npm yesterday for learning purpose, the weekly downloads of this package has become 170 today. Can anyone explain if they are real users or it happens to every new package.

Screenshot Attached

I am expecting a clarification on this query

Comment: It's likely automated tooling getting information on packages. If there's 0 users including yourself you can expect that number to go down again.